# How do I know if I run on Amazon EC2 windows instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I try to figure out whether I run on regular computer or ec2 (from JVM based app). The simple method could be attempt to get [instance data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html), however that means I should wait until timeout, and it does not feel right. Is there a quicker way to know this?

Comment: In my case it's windows

Comment: Please edit your question to include this relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon Windows AMIs come with the "EC2Config" service installed.  If we can make some assumptions about your environment (like... you're not also running some service called EC2Config locally), then you may be able to take advantage of this.

If you can list the services available on your machine, you can search for the [EC2Config](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/UsingConfig_WinAMI.html) service. Here's an example in PowerShell where I use `Get-Service`, and return true if the count of services named "Ec2Config" is greater than zero:

On EC2:

```
PS C:\> @(Get-Service -Name "Ec2Config" -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue').Count -gt 0
True
```

On Local:

```
PS C:\> @(Get-Service -Name "Ec2Config" -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue').Count -gt 0
False
```

I can't help you with a Java implementation, but some quick googling suggests it shouldn't be too bad.